# How to mount TV to basement wall under stairs?

Tags: mounting, studs, television

I have a 55" TV I'd like to mount on a basement wall, which is located under the stairs. The area under the stairs is actually accessible, and I've gone back there to see what's available. It looks like there are studs there, but they're only 2 1/4" x 1 1/2"? Here is a picture:

[image: under stairs]

Here the sloping ceiling is the underbelly of the stairs.

Is there any way to mount this TV to this wall safely and securely? Sorry if this is an easy question, I'm a complete novice at this.

**Edit**: some more photos.

Here's the front of the wall:
[image: front of wall]

Here's some better pics of the back of the wall:

[image: back of wall]

[image: another]

Comment: A photo with some context would help. It's not at all clear what framing is available and what that piece of hardware is. Chances are you can go ahead and mount to those studs though. Worst case scenario you see some flexing and add some cross-braces to tie things together behind the wall.

Comment: @isherwood: ok I'll edit and add some more photos from both sides of the wall. That thing in the pic is actually a recessed speaker. Would it make sense to add some cross-braces beforehand? And do you have any links on how to do that?

Comment: So where's the TV going? And I still don't really have a wide enough view to see what I'm looking at. What's going on at the right edge of the photos? Is that another wall coming in at a 90?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see there was apparently already a TV mounted there beforehand.

[image]

The person who installed the dual speaker assembly cut off one of the studs and this could be of some concern. You could try to anchor that stud to the side of the stair support to make the stud more secure. Alternatively you could screw a flat 2x4 down (shown as red outline) on top of the lower plate just under the speaker assembly. Then a second flat piece of 2x4 depicted in the yellow outline could be screwed to the added red piece and into the stub of the stud above. The stud may need to be shimmed out with an appropriate piece of wood cut to size. From your pictures this looks like it would clear the rear end of that one speaker. Do use screws to fasten the pieces as the pounding of nails with a hammer would likely blister the nails/screws that hold the drywall in place. Since the added 2x4 pieces are relatively small it would also be advisable to use some construction adhesive to glue the pieces together before screwing. Once set the glue will make the assembly much more solid.

[image]

So as long as you put the sturdy mounting screws for the TV bracket into the studs in a proper manner (i.e. predrill with the correct diameter pilot drill) to prevent splitting of the studs you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes the previous owner had a TV mounted there, but I was concerned because the manual for the mount I have suggested drilling into 2x4 studs. I've never mounted a tv under the stairs like this.

Comment: Also, in your very helpful picture, what is the red piece attaching to? The piece of wood beneath the speaker, or the speaker itself?

Comment: The red outlined piece would be laid flat on top of the existing lower plate or header block that itself is laying flat under the speaker unit. You would not want to attach anything to that flimsy plastic speaker frame.